# Run separate sets of child sequential fadeIns at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm basically wanting numerous graphs to load in their components sequentially, but each graph to do this at the same time. Currently it loads in the base ($graphName) at the same time, but the rest of the items are all relative to the next elements loaded in. I'm guessing i need to namespace this but how would i integrate that into this function?

```
    $graphName.fadeIn(500, function(){
        $graphaxes.each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(800, function(){
                $(".circle").each(function(index) {
                    $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(800);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="graph">
            <div class="x-axis">
                <span>Effectiveness</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="y-axis">
                <span>Cost</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="name brand-awareness">
                <li class="circle bk top"></li>
                <li class="circle bk bottom"></li>

                <li class="circle one"><p>INCENTIVATED</p></li>
                <li class="circle two"><p>RTB</p></li>
                <li class="circle three"><p>AD <br> NETWORK</p></li>
                <li class="circle four"><p>SMS</p></li>
                <li class="circle five"><p>WIFI</p></li>
                <li class="circle six"><p>SOCIAL</p></li>
                <li class="circle seven"><p>DIRECT/ <br> PREMIUM</p></li>
                <li class="circle eight"><p>VIDEO/ <br> RICH</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply fadeIn function directly to jQuery result (not inside jQuery.each):

```
$graphName.fadeIn(500, function() {
    $graphaxes.delay(500*index).fadeIn(800, function() {
        $(".circle").delay(500*index).fadeIn(800);
    });
});
```